# Spinner select the same item twice

Tags: android, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I created a spinner filled by flags and a country code number for each flag:

[image]

But I'm facing an issue. When I remove the country code number on my editText, I want to be able to go back to the spinner and click one more time on the flag and display the correct country code that I've just removed.

But at the moment I can't trigger the event ***OnItemSelectedListener*** a second time.

- Use case:

Here for instance with the UK flag and code, I go through the spinner I select UK flag, my event ***OnItemSelectedListner*** is triggered and +44 country code is set into my editText.

Then by mistake I remove it, so I'm going back to my spinner I click a new time on my UK flag but nothing happen, my event ***OnItemSelectedListner*** is not triggered, while I clicked on my flag.

At this point if I click on an other flat in the list, its code will be display and I can go back on UK flag click on it to display the code and this time it work.

I'm trying to figure out why I can't trigger this event: ***OnItemSelectedListner*** a second time. It's like my item is already selected no event is possible at this point.

My code:

```
new AsyncPhoneInitTask(currentActivity.this).execute();// fetch data to fill spinner
countrySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
countrySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener);
countryAdapter = new CountryAdapter(currentActivity.this);
countrySpinner.setAdapter(countryAdapter);

// I want to trigger this event a second time
protected AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Country c = (Country) countrySpinner.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // My code
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    };
```

Is there a way to solve my issue ?

I would like to have an event ***setOnItemClickListener*** and not setOnItemSelectedListener. Because here it's the reason why I can't reselect the same item twice, it has been already selected.

Comment: Could you show the code you use to re-open or re-initialize your spinner? If somehow the second time there is no onItemSelectedListener attached to the spinner then that could be the source of your problem.

Comment: @FrankD. I don't have any code to reinitialize my spinner. I just want to have an event setOnItemClickListener and not setOnItemSelectedListener. Because here it's the reason why I can't reselect the same item, it has been already selected.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround I found is to have a "placeholder" in the spinner, like the first item in the list is "Choose country". Then add

```
countrySpinner.setSelection(0);
```

to the `onItemSelected()`. This forces the spinner to swap which item is selected, causing the `onItemSelected()` to happen twice, once with the users intended selection and once with the "Choose country" option. Since this workaround also triggers onItemSelected again, you need a check at the start to avoid an infinate loop.

```
int positionOfPlaceholder = 0;

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    //Check if the first element is choosen
    if(i == positionOfPlaceholder){
        return;
    }
    Country c = (Country) countrySpinner.getItemAtPosition(position);

    //Code

    countrySpinner.setSelection(positionOfPlaceholder);
}
```

Problem here is that the choosen value is never shown in the spinner, as it looks like you also want...